# How to enable/disable button based on a value from the ViewModel?

Tags: html, asp.net, button, razor, model-view-controller

I am setting the following values into the `ViewModel` in the `ActionMethod` before passing the `ViewModel` to the `View`:

```
if(toDateNullEntries.Count > 0)
{
    locationsHistoryVM.IsOpen = false;
}
else
{
    locationsHistoryVM.IsOpen = true;
}
```

In my View, I have the following `Button` which is `disabled` from beginning.

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn bgm-orange waves-effect mybtn" id="LocateSubmitButton" disabled>SAVE</button>
</div>
```

Now, I want to `enable` it if the `IsOpen` value from the `ViewModel` is `true`. If not, I want it to remain `disabled`. How can I do that?

**Edit**

I tried sending the `IsOpen` value via `ViewBag` and then I checked the value with `jQuery` in the following way:

```
if(@ViewBag.IsOpen === "false"){
    $('#LocateSubmitButton').removeAttr("disabled");

})
```

However, I was getting the following error in this case:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined

On performing `Inspect Element`, I see that the code is trying to compare `False === false`.

The reason why I don't want to continue with `ViewBag` is because I know it is a bad practice and I want to use `ViewModel`. Is there a way to implement the same using `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional attributes:

```
<button disabled="@(Model.IsOpen == false)">SAVE</button>
```

If the condition evaluates to `true`, the attribute will be there, otherwise it will not be there.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by mixing some c# with Razor code like this:

```
<button class="btn"
        title="Button that can be disabled conditionally by view model property on Razor template\HTML"
        type="button"
        @{
            if (ViewModel.BooleanProperty == true)
            {
                @:disabled="disabled"
            }
         }>
```

Depending on the `BooleanProperty` value, the `disabled` attribute will get added to the button's HTML code; otherwise `disabled` won't be present at all and the button will remain enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The following makes the output of "disabled" conditional based on a value from the model:

```
<button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn bgm-orange waves-effect mybtn" id="LocateSubmitButton" @if (!Model.IsOpen) { <text>disabled</text> }>SAVE</button>
```

if you wanted to do what you tried with the ViewBag, it would look like this:

```
if("@ViewBag.IsOpen" === "False"){
    $('#LocateSubmitButton').removeAttr("disabled");
})
```

Notice, the quotes around the item so the comparison becomes "False" === "False" at runtime.